# In Processing 2, How would I make this happen?

Tags: processing

In Processing 2, How would I make this happen?

First left click of the mouse should display ball centered where mouse was when clicked.

Second left click of the mouse should display another ball centered where the mouse was when clicked.

Once both balls are displayed, a left click will launch 1st ball at the second ball.

When the 1st ball touches the edge of the second ball, the 1st ball should stop and the second ball should move in the same direction at the same speed and move the same amount of distance that the 1st ball moved

Comment: Show us what you already have. We want to fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: You can start on [this link](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/create-new-object-with-mouse-click.html)

Comment: Third part I need to shoot the cue ball at the target ball and it must travel the distance equal to which the cue ball travel.

(click==4){
    initialDistance = dist(target.xpos,target.ypos,cue.xpos,cue.ypos);
    difx = target.xpos-cue.xpos;
    dify = target.ypos-cue.ypos;
    text("3. Aiming Shot!",20,340);
    target.update();
    cue.update();
  }
  else if(click==5){
   currentDistance = dist(target.xpos,target.ypos,cue.xpos,cue.ypos);
  if(currentDistance > cue.ballDiam){
      //travel is still away from middle, move travel
      cue.xpos+=difx/speed;
      cue.ypos+=dify/speed;
    }

Comment: Code is hard to read in comments. Add it to the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you code for this, as that would be too involved (and isn't the purpose of Stack Overflow anyway). However, I'll outline some of the principles you'll need, and hopefully you can go from there.

The first thing to do is keep track of the state. It sounds like your states will be:

1. Waiting for first click.
2. Waiting for second click.
3. Moving 1st ball.
4. Moving 2nd ball.

This approach is quite common, and is sometimes referred to as a Finite State Machine. Typically you'd define a constant integer for each state, and store a "current state" integer somewhere. It will be updated when you want to change/advance state.

In the main drawing loop, you'd execute different code depending on which state you're in. For example, in the third state, it will draw both balls, and keep on moving the 1st ball closer to the second 2nd, calculating the distance between them. When they touch, it moves on to the fourth state.

You'll obviously need a mouse handler to detect and handle clicks. That will store the ball positions and advance the state appropriately.

For the mathematical side of it, you'll need two things. First, you'll need to get comfortable using vector maths (specifically, normalising a vector to calculate direction, and multiplying it up to get a desired speed). Secondly, you'll need to use the Euclidean distance formula (basically just Pythagoras' theorem) to calculate the distance between the balls, determining when they're close enough to touch each other. There are loads of tutorials online for all this stuff which you may find useful.

If you get stuck on a particular issue in your coding, feel free to post a more specific question (although always bear in mind it may have been asked/answered already).

Comment: 1st & 2nd click done! Now? 3rd?
  
  else if(click==4){
   
    initialDistance = dist(target.xpos,target.ypos,cue.xpos,cue.ypos);
    difx = target.xpos-cue.xpos;
    dify = target.ypos-cue.ypos;
    text("3. Aiming Shot!",20,340);
    target.update();
    cue.update();
    
  }
  
  else if(click==5){
   
   currentDistance = dist(target.xpos,target.ypos,cue.xpos,cue.ypos);
  
  if(currentDistance > cue.ballDiam){
      //travel is still away from middle, move travel
      cue.xpos+=difx/speed;
      cue.ypos+=dify/speed;
      text("it's going",10,360);
    } 
    
  }
  
 
  click++;
  
}